# nodejs and jquery - passing and saving a binary file

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, fs

**What I'm trying to do**

Upload a binary file (a .docx in this case) from the browser and save it on the server. Using NodeJs/ExpressJS on the server.

**Issue**

I can successfully pass text files (.json/.txt/.csv) from the client to server and save successfully, however I seem to be unable to do it for a binary file. I either get "no conversion from text to binary" error with a corrupted file with no data in it, or an internal error.

**Client side**

After the input upload, I call

```
fRead.readAsArrayBuffer(fName);
```

The $.ajax call is

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: obj, //the obj is the e.target.result from FileReader
        contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
        dataType: 'binary',
        success: function (data) {
            cbFn(data.msg);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert("error " + status + " " + error);
        }
    });
```

**Server Side**

On the server side

```
fs.writeFile(saveFile, req.body, 'binary', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('file saved to ' + saveFile);
});
```

Now on the server side, the code above throws the "no conversion from text to binary" error though it saves the file (corrupted, no data). If I change it to

```
fs.writeFile(saveFile, Buffer.from(req.body), 'binary', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('file saved to ' + saveFile);
});
```

I just get an internal error.

At this point I'm at a loss as to where my error is - is it that I'm using the wrong encoding types in my $.ajax call? Or my options in fs.writeFile are wrong, or maybe I shouldn't be using fs.writeFile at all and something else? I feel like there's so many permutations so I could use a little help.

Also surprised it's been pretty hard to find a good online article for this case - am just trying to upload a binary file and save it!

Answer (score -1):

Don't read it as arrayBuffer with the FileReader, just send the blob as is

```
var file = new Blob(["321"])
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/upload.php',
    data: file,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
})
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you created the file. Once I have the fileReader object, what do I need to do to read the content before sending to server? I tried your method above, by simply passing the 'e' from fileReader.onload = function(e), and also e.target and e.target.result. Doesn't work. The nodejs server shows it has no req.body...

Comment: screw the FileReader... i assume `fName` is the blob so just send the fName as `data`